# Jquery: if class exists

Tags: jquery, class, find

I want something that finds instantly on the page a class called `prop` and set it to `hidden` soon as there is one.

**IMPORTANT: soon as a new element is added I want that element with prop class changed. Like a while loop**

```
if( class='prop' == found ){

     set class to ('hidden');

}
```

And yes this function is inserted after the element caller. but it seems like it takes some time till the element is generated so I need a check on the class to remove it as fast as possible. I cant use a delay in this case have tried that with bad results.

Comment: Does this mean you are adding the elements with class `prop` dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $('.prop').hide()

Documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Or if you want to add a class 'hidden' instead:

> $('.prop').addClass('hidden')

Comment: is that working like a while loop? or does it just toggle? I need some kind of a IF(){ --- }

Comment: Instead of using a while loop why not trigger this call when ever an element is added. Seems more efficient

Comment: see @Avanq answer... A generic solution though I would suggest it to call manually rather than on "DomNodeInserted" ..

Comment: It does no properly work cuz the calculation of the element function will take longer on every diffrent computer. so I need something like a loop or just a if check in that function. yes something like that. thanks for reply

Answer (score 13):

You need hasClass function

```
if($('selector').hasClass('prop'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass("prop");
        $(this).addClass("hidden");
    }
```

This might help

Answer (score 1):

javascript has [some events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events) that keep track of changes in DOM, you can use those.

```
$('body').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(){
  $('.prop', this).hide();
});
```